# The center and centralizer of a group.

Tags: group-theory

If $Z(G)$ denotes the center of the group $G$ and, for $a\in G$, $C(a)$ denotes its centralizer, then show that $a\in Z(G)$ if and only if $C(a)=G$.

I got as far to to proving if $a$ is in $Z(G)$ then $C(a)=G$. But I am having trouble going going the other way  ( If $C(a)=G$ then $a$ is in $Z(G)$.)

Here is my proof of the second statement. 
Assume $C(a)=G$. 
WTS $a$ is an element of $Z(G)$. 
Let $k$ be an element of $G$. 
Since $C(a)=G$, then $k$ is an element of $C(a)$. 
By definition $ak = ka$ for $k$ is an element of $G$. 
Then $a$ is an element of $G$. 
Hence, $a$ is an element of $Z(G)$.

Comment: No. You can proceed directly in both directions, using nothing but the definitions.

Comment: Thank you I will attempt that.

Answer (score 1):

By definitions.The center of a group G, denoted $Z(G)$, is the set of elements that commute with every element of G. While the centralizer of $a $ is a set of elements that commute with $a $.If $a$ is an element of  $Z$, $xa = ax$ for all $x$ of  $G$, whence $C(a) = G$. If, conversely, 
$C(a) = G$, $xa =ax$ for all $x$ of $G$, so that $a$ is an element of center because commute with all elements of group.